# Is there a way to automatically answer alert boxes that pop up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to overwrite an Excel file but whenever it gets to save an alert box apperars asking if I want to overwrite the original file. What can I do to auto confirm that? I already tried putting the alert on the foreground and confirming through the keyboard module but I need a method that does it without showing it on the screen.

A friend once told me about a command that does something similar but I can't quite remember, it was `setDefaultflag = False` or something.

Here's the code if it helps in any way.

````
import os
import shutil
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

print("Opening Excel ...")
xl=win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
shutil.copy("C:/(...)/MIS_RISCOS_UPDATE_antOriginal.xlsx", "/MIS_RISCOS_UPDATE_ant.xlsx")

print("Opening Workbook ...")
wb=xl.workbooks.open("C:/(...)/MIS_RISCOS_UPDATE_ant.xlsx")
xl.Visible=False

print("Refreshing Queries, Please Wait!")
wb.RefreshAll()
xl.Visible=False

xl.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
print("Refresh Completed Sucessfully!")

print("Saving File")
wb.save
sleep(5)

print("Closing Process")
xl.Quit()
os.system("taskkill /f /im excel.exe")
exit()```
````

Comment: Are you doing this serverside or clientside? Sounds like you are replacing serverside - in which case - just programmatically delete the file and save with the new file. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a local file, the code works as intended but whenever it gets to save it a prompt shows up, I just need to make it so that it presses the yes button and overwrites the file

Comment: Sorry @Kuzhin - I should have clarified. Is your script running and then the output of your script is the excel file which is directly written to the drive or is it pushing the output to a user who then interacts with the output to save it somewhere else.  If it is the first - then you can do open(filename,'w') and then write to file.

Comment: Ahh ok - Are you able to try xl.DisplayAlerts = False and see what happens please

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Ok - I will add this as an answer in case it helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DisplayAlerts = False` so in this case it will be `xl.DisplayAlerts = False`